# How to appropriately predict/classify using smf.mnlogit.predict()?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels, multinomial

I'm curious if someone can help me understand an effective way of getting a single vector of predictions using .predict() for the multinomial logistic regression using `statsmodels.formula.api.mnlogit()`

```
import pandas as pd, statsmodels.formula.api as smf

df = pd.DataFrame({'age': np.random.choice([20, 30, 23, 40, 39, 27], size = 100, replace = True), 
                  'animal': np.random.choice(['dog', 'parrot', 'cat', 'turtle'], size = 100, 
                                             replace = True)})

mod = smf.mnlogit('animal ~ age', df).fit()

predictions = mod.predict(df['age'])
print(predictions)
```

This will output a matrix shape of 100 rows x 4 columns:[.predict() outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqVuO.png)

I'm guessing this is the classification probability of the value to one of the four output variables from `df.animals.unique()`?

I'm guessing I'd create a function to assign each value to one of the four DVs using the highest probability score in the row from the `.predict()` outputs?

Comment: `predictions.argmax(1)` will give you the index of the choice with the highest predicted probability. or maybe `np.asarray(predictions).argmax(1)`

Comment: Thank you @Josef - `np.asarray(predictions).argmax(1)` works well!

Comment: @Josef Do you happen to know how I can find out which dependent values correspond to each of the indices? For example, index 0 = 'dog', etc.?

Comment: That should be in `mod.model.data.ynames` but also in some of the returns, e.g. summary and `mod.params` DataFrame as index.